# Html table reduce white space between columns

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

[image]

```html
<table>
  <thead id="main-table-head">
    <tr id="aa">
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>21 Oct 2022</td>
      <td>dfd</td>
      <td>lk;</td>
      <td>hjk</td>
      <td>hjk</td>
      <td>hjkh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21 Oct 2022</td>
      <td>dfd</td>
      <td>lk;</td>
      <td>hjk</td>
      <td>hjk</td>
      <td>hjkh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21 Oct 2022</td>
      <td>dfd</td>
      <td>lk;</td>
      <td>hjk</td>
      <td>hjk</td>
      <td>hjkh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21 Oct 2022</td>
      <td>dfd</td>
      <td>lk;</td>
      <td>hjk</td>
      <td>hjk</td>
      <td>hjkh</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td className="footer-td">5866.23</td>
      <td className="footer-td">456</td>
      <td className="footer-td">5688</td>
      <td className="footer-td">543</td>
      <td className="footer-td">86</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h5 className="total-label">Grand Total</h5>
      </td>
      <td>5866.23</td>
      <td>456</td>
      <td>5688</td>
      <td>543</td>
      <td>86</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Here is my Html table. it contains some data. I am working in react project. before mapping data to table body ,  I designed main structure of the table. when  I adding long length data , "B" column went to right-side. So I want reduce the white space between "A" column and "B" column. I tried so many ways. especially cellspacing was used. It did not work. please some one help me. white space is depend on where we write at A column things. but it should not be happened to my task.

Comment: Please also provide your CSS

Comment: Based on your screenshot, there is a lot of relevant CSS that needs to be included in the question for this to be answerable.

Comment: it's because your table width is 100% - you could give a fixed width to columns b to f and make a take up the rest of the space, otherwsie you would just need to make your table a fixed width (or give it a max width)

Comment: Add relevant CSS to your snippet, as for now, we can only guess what needs to be done/corrected. [reprex], please!

Answer (score 0):

You can add  custom spaces in **th** tags
Such as :

- `<th width="100px">A</th>`
- `<th width="20%">A</th>`

**`<th width="pixels|%">`**

Comment: This is not valid HTML. The `width` attribute should only contain a number, in pixels (but without the "px" unit). Sizing in any other unit should be done in CSS using the `style` attribute. Most browsers will correct this mistake and do what you intended, but it's still incorrect.

Comment: `table { border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {padding: 0;
}`


The **border-collapse** table definition gets rid of the spacing and the padding in this instance removes all padding from a cell